# Finding Optimal Dual Solution without solving de Dual Problem (knowing the Optimal Primal Solution)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, simplex

I've been asked to solve this problem using the Dual Simplex Method. 
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min:  & x_1+6x_2+3x_3 \\
\text{s.t}:  & -4x_1-4x_2-2x_3+x_4=-18 \\
& 2x_1+2x_2-4x_3+x_5 = -16 \\
& x_j \geq 0, \; j=1,\dots,5
\end{array}
$$
Once I solved it, I got the Optimal Primal Solution is $x_1=2, \, x_3=5, \, x_2=x_4=x_5=0 \; \text{and} \; z = 17.$

**Now I want to find the Optimal Dual Solution without solving de Dual Problem (just knowing the Optimal Primal Solution). But I don't know how to proceed.**

Comment: Just formulate the dual problem. Then you can deduce the optimal solution, without solving the dual problem

Comment: @callculus Once I have $$
\begin{array}{ll}
\max:  & -18y_1-16y_2 \\
\text{s.t}:  & -4y_1+2y_2 \leq 1\\
& -4y_1+2y_2 \leq 6\\
& -2y_1-4y_2 \leq 3\\
& y_1 \leq 0, \; y_2 \leq 0
\end{array}
$$ What should I do next? (in case I formulate de dual problem properly)

Comment: Now apply complementary slackness based on $x_1>0$ and $x_3>0$ to deduce that dual constraints 1 and 3 are satisfied with equality.

Comment: @mug_donut Any further questions?

Comment: @callculus No actually, thanks anyway :)